# How to calculate discrete probablity in python efficiently?

Tags: python, performance, recursion

How can I calculate the probability function of the sum of N discrete random variables?

So far I've come up with a recursive solution:

```py
def calculate_from(start, path, L):
    if start == len(path) - 1:
        return 1 if L < 0 else 0
    else:
        return sum([p * calculate_from(start + 1, path, L - value) for value, p in times_distribution[path[start]]])

N = 15
times_distribution = [[[v, 1 / 4] for v in (30, 60, 90, 120)] for n in range(N)]
times_distribution[0] = [[0, 1]]

path = list(range(N)) + [0]
L = 1000

prob = 1 - calculate_from(0, path, L)
```

But it works too slow. I realize that any exact calculation of such probability would have exponential complexity, however I suppose that recursion is not the very efficient way to calculate it. Is there a way to do it more efficiently? N is up to 20.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem statement. Is `times_distribution` supposed to represent a graph data structure? Are you sure the "times" are associated with nodes, rather than edges? What is a "total duration of a path" - the sum of node "times" along the path, or something else? When you speak of a "subset of these nodes", do you mean some nodes that represent a valid path from a defined start and end point within the graph? Or do you mean literally any subset of the set of nodes? Or just what? Please read [ask] and set up the problem statement more clearly.

Comment: you can use memorization to reduce timing and avoid repeated result

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, practically I am asking about computing the distribution function of sum of discrete random variables. `times_distribution` represents distribution of these variables. Graph set up is just for illustration where the problem arises, it doesn't really matter, so I removed that part.

Comment: Are your discrete random variables always going to be chosen from the same sequence, which is `[n, 2*n, 3*n...]` etc.? If so, you can greatly simplify by using combinatorics to figure out the number of ways to create `k*n` from the inputs. Otherwise, I'm not sure that it's possible to avoid an exponential blow-up of runtime.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, no, unfortunately I cannot guarantee that all of them will by identically distributed. That is why I am asking about efficient implementation, not the reduction of complexity. Maybe it is possible to highly reduce the constant in overall asymptotic.